# How to get selective data from a file in TCL?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to parse selective data from a file based on certain key words using tcl,for example I have a file like this

```
...
...
..
... 
data_start
30 abc1 xyz 
90 abc2 xyz 
214 abc3 xyz
data_end
...
...
...
```

How do I catch only the 30, 90 and 214 between "data_start" and "data_end"? What I have so far(tcl newbie),

```
proc get_data_value{ data_file } {

set lindex 0
set fp [open $data_file r]
set filecontent [read $fp]



while {[gets $filecontent line] >= 0} {

if { [string match "data_start" ]} {

    #Capture only the first number? 
    #Use regex? or something else? 

        if { [string match "data_end" ] } {

            break
        } else {

            ##Do Nothing?
        }
    }
 }
close $fp
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is smaller in size, then you can use `read` command to slurp the whole data into a variable and then apply `regexp` to extract the required information.

**input.txt**

```
data_start
30 abc1 xyz 
90 abc2 xyz 
214 abc3 xyz
data_end
data_start
130 abc1 xyz 
190 abc2 xyz 
1214 abc3 xyz
data_end
```

**extractNumbers.tcl**

```
set fp [open input.txt r]
set data [read $fp]
close $fp
set result [regexp -inline -all {data_start.*?\n(\d+).*?\n(\d+).*?\n(\d+).*?data_end} $data]
foreach {whole_match number1 number2 number3} $result {
    puts "$number1, $number2, $number3"
}
```

**Output :**

```
30, 90, 214
130, 190, 1214
```

**Update :**

Reading a larger file's content into a single variable will cause the program to crash depends on the memory of your PC. When I tried to read a file of size 890MB with `read` command in a Win7 8GB RAM laptop, I got `unable to realloc 531631112 bytes` error message and `tclsh` crashed. After some bench-marking found that it is able to read a file with a size of 500,015,901 bytes. But the program will consume 500MB of memory since it has to hold the data.

Also, having a variable to hold this much data is not efficient when it comes to extracting the information via `regexp`. So, in such cases, it is better to go ahead with read the content line by line.

Read more about this [here](http://wiki.tcl.tk/348#pagetoc6498b255).

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, this works exactly like I need. What is the trade off if I have a really large file? Just processing time?

Answer (score 1):

Load all the data from the file into a variable. Set start and end tokens and seek to those positions.  Process the item line by line.  Tcl uses lists of strings separated by white space so we can process the items in the line with foreach {a b c} $line {...}.

tcl:

```
set data {...
...
..
... 
data_start
30 abc1 xyz 
90 abc2 xyz 
214 abc3 xyz
data_end
...
...
...}


set i 0
set start_str "data_start"
set start_len [string length $start_str]
set end_str "data_end"
set end_len [string length $end_str]

while {[set start [string first $start_str $data $i]] != -1} {
    set start [expr $start + $start_len]
    set end [string first $end_str $data $start]
    set end [expr $end - 1]  
    set item [string range $data $start $end]
    set lines [split $item "\n"]

    foreach {line} $lines {
        foreach {a b c} $line {
            puts "a=$a, b=$b, c=$c"
        }
    }

    set i [expr $end + $end_len]
}
```

output:

```
a=30, b=abc1, c=xyz
a=90, b=abc2, c=xyz
a=214, b=abc3, c=xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write that as

```
set fid [open $data_file]
set p 0
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    switch -regexp -- $line { 
        {^data_end}   {set p 0} 
        {^data_start} {set p 1} 
        default {
            if {$p && [regexp {^(\d+)\M} $line -> num]} {
                lappend nums $num
            }
        }
    }
}
close $fid
puts $nums
```

or, even

```sh
set nums [exec sed -rn {/data_start/,/data_end/ {/^([[:digit:]]+).*/ s//\1/p}} $data_file]
puts $nums
```

Comment: Regular expressions are expensive and entirely uncalled for in this context. Exec-ing a separate process is an abomination on its own -- and also happens to make the script unportable.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method would be to declare `proc`s for each of the *acceptable* tokens and utilize the [`unknown` mechanism](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/unknown.html) to quietly ignore the unacceptable ones.

```tcl
proc 30 args {
    ... handle 30 $args
}

proc 90 args {
    ... process 90 $args
}

rename unknown original_unknown
proc unknown args {
    # This space was deliberately left blank
}

source datafile.txt
rename original_unknown unknown
```

You'll be using Tcl's built-in parsing, which should be considerably faster. It also looks better in my opinion.

You can also put the line-handling logic into your `unknown`-procedure entirely:

```tcl
rename unknown original_unknown
proc unknown {first args} {
    process $first $args
}
source input.txt
rename original_unknown unknown
```

Either way, the trick is that Tcl's own parser (implemented in C) will be breaking up the input lines into tokens for you -- so you don't have to implement the parsing in Tcl yourself.

This does not always work -- if, for example, the input is using multi-line syntax (without `{` and `}`) or if the tokens are separated with something other than white space. But in your case it should do nicely.